# Qt + OpenCV in Debian

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, debian

I am trying to use Qt and OpenCV in a Raspberry running Debian.

I installed Qt, then I installed OpenCV, the process has been painful but I did it (separate examples in Qt and in OpenCV work fine).

However, when I try to add opencv functions in Qt I get the following error:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

I did this and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH looks like this:

```
/home/pi/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/unix-install
```

Where there is the opencv.pc file.

What am I doing wrong? There are a few questions about similar issues, but they don't solve my problem and I am wasting days to solve a boring installation problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file 'opencv.pc' is often located in "$(OPENCV_DIR)/lib/pkgconfig" path.

Then you have to set environment variable like this:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(PKG_CONFIG_PATH):<pcDir>
```